# Avoid future warning triggered by pandas.Float64Index

Tags: python, pandas

Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
data = sns.load_dataset('tips').iloc[0:5, [2,6]]
```

I use the below function to automatically generate bar plots for each variable in the data:

```
import numpy as np
ncols = 2
nrows = int(np.ceil(data.shape[1] / ncols))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols,
                         figsize=(4*ncols, 3*nrows), sharex=True)

for ax, (name, g) in zip(axes.ravel(), data.items()):
    z = g.value_counts(normalize=True, ascending=True) * 100
    if isinstance(z.index, (pd.Int64Index)):
        z = z.sort_index(ascending=False)
    z.plot.barh(ax=ax)
    ax.title.set_text(name)
```

It works, and bars are automatically plotted in most to least frequent order (e.g. sex), except for **numerical** categories, which are plotted in numerical order (e.g. size):

[image]

That said, the function also triggers this future warning:

```
FutureWarning: pandas.Int64Index is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.Index with the appropriate dtype instead.
```

I have tried:

```
if isinstance(z.index, (int)):
```

The above does not generate a warning, but bars are not sorted as I wish.

I have also tried:

```
if isinstance(z.index, (pd.Index(datatype='int64'))):
```

But this triggers an error, `Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, None was passed`. In this last case, I also don't know how to specify both float and int.

Comment: `value_counts()` on float values is not a good idea. You might want to pass a `bins` to `value_counts`. Aslo, `z.index` would have an instance of `pd.Index` not, float or int.

Comment: @Quang Hoang I know. What about the integers (eg variable size)? I am mostly interested in the integers. This dataset is just for illustration purposes

Comment: For integers though, it really depends on your data. If you (can) consider them as categorical, e.g. hour of the day, then `value_counts()` make sense, otherwise, e.g. height of a person in cm, then `value_counts` with `bins` or `hist()` would work a lot better.

Comment: I have now edited my question to only include integers. Can someone now help please

Comment: FYI, you can just check **before** you count `z`: if `g.dtype == int or g.dtype == float`?